# Beginner friendly open source projects in O.R

Tags: software, open-source

The title says it all: **Are there any open source projects, that are open to new contributers?**

- If not, should there be?
- If yes, what are they and what is the best way to get involved?

Comment: Maybe one thing you could try is testing. Beat the hell out of the codes and try to find previously undocumented bugs, weaknesses, opportunities for improvement, etc. Then report your findings.

Answer (score 14):

[VRPy](https://vrpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/) is a python library for solving a range of vehicle routing problems.

It is open source and open to new contributors.

There are at least two ways to contribute:

- solve one of the existing [issues](https://github.com/Kuifje02/vrpy/issues)
- have fun with it and propose new enhancements based on your personal experience with the library

Comment: also checkout [cspy](https://github.com/torressa/cspy), one of the dependencies of vrpy. good stuff !

Comment: Thanks for the shout out :)

Answer (score 10):

There are lots of projects at [COIN-OR](https://www.coin-or.org), many of which I'm sure would welcome contributions. You would need to discuss with the individual project developers what the best way to help would be, but one thing that's nearly always welcome is help with documentation, including reference manuals, tutorials, example code calling library functions, etc.

Answer (score 9):

[Here](https://awesomeopensource.com/projects/linear-programming/operations-research) and [here](https://github.com/topics/operations-research) (list is generated by Github based on the tags on the open projects) you can find long lists of open operations research projects on Github. By clicking on the "Open Issues" link on each page you can directly access the Github repository for that specific project. Note that @Kuifje's own repository *VRPy* is a great example.

Comment: Thanks for your kind words !

Answer (score 2):

[Timefold Solver](https://timefold.ai) and [our quickstarts](https://github.com/TimefoldAI/timefold-quickstarts) are open to external contributors, under the open-source Apache License.

At the time of writing, we have [more than 300 Pull Requests](https://github.com/TimefoldAI/timefold-solver/pulls?q=is%3Apr%20) in less than a year, with a portion of those coming from outside contributors. If you don't know where to start, reach out to us on [GitHub Discussions](https://github.com/TimefoldAI/timefold-solver/discussions).

But you don't need to contribute code to participate. You can also [raise an issue](https://github.com/TimefoldAI/timefold-solver/issues) or improve the writing in [the docs](https://github.com/TimefoldAI/timefold-solver/tree/main/docs).

Hint: **Start small.** Less than 10 lines. It will be easier to finish for you and much easier/faster for our core team to review and approve. Just like in any other open source project, build trust and experience, before you submit a PR of 100+ lines.